# VSCode extension custom view setup

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write a custom VSCode view that I want to behave similar to how the debuggers work. Meaning that when you click on the view in the activity bar, it will ask you to set it up if it hasn't been. How do you do that?

Here's how I created the view in package.json,

```
        "viewsContainers": {
            "activitybar": [
                {
                    "id": "my-view",
                    "title": "My View",
                    "icon": "images/my-icon.svg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "views": {
            "my-view": [
                {
                    "id": "child-view-1",
                    "name": "Child View 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "child-view-2",
                    "name": "Child View 2"
                }
            ]
        },
```

My icon shows up in the activity bar and my child views are shown when I click on it. How do I customize that behavior? When my icon is clicked, I want it to check if it's been set up before and run my setup code if it hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

The "On click command" is set at tree item creation, in the command parameter of the object, like below:

```
new Dependency(moduleName, version, vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None, {
                        command: 'extension.openPackageOnNpm',
                        title: '',
                        arguments: [moduleName]
```

That click should call another command defined in to accept the input and process accordingly.  This assumes that the view has a default item created by the tree view class instantiation.

This example has really helped me get my view all setup:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/29b21d108d4575003278060faaa3eab0f7374979/tree-view-sample/src/nodeDependencies.ts#L52

Furthermore, this extension has some good use of populating a tree view with default options, that your users could click to kick off getting an environment setup:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-cosmosdb

If, in your example, the environment hasn't been setup yet, and I presume that there would be no objects in the view list to click on, then a welcome view, like below, should provide an option to get the user moving in the right direction.
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#welcome-content